# Batch - Variable working only in second run

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I try to make a simple application that will SSH connect to my favourite server.

It is actually working!

But the problem is when I add the 3rd option (which is Custom)..

So I add the 3rd option and make the app to ask users the `IP Address` and `Username`

However, the value inserted is not set in the variable...

And the SSH connection will failed because there is no value in `IP Address` and `Username` ..

Then I run once again the batch file, choose 3rd option, then insert another value, then the value appear seems to be the value that is set in 1st run.

Sorry for my bad english...

Anyone can try my script below, and try to connect twice with different value. Then you will understand.

```
@echo off
cls
set custom_choice=3
echo Which server do you want to connect?
echo 1. 232
echo 2. Kiwire Free Edition
echo 3. Custom
echo.
set /p choice="Enter your choice: "
echo.

IF %choice%==1 (
    ::this is comment
    ssh root@192.168.0.232
) ELSE IF %choice%==2 (
    ssh -i ./key/my-ssh-key-normal dev@123.123.123.123
) ELSE IF %choice%==%custom_choice% (
    set /p conIpAddress="Please insert IP Address: "
    set /p conUsername="Please insert Username: "
    echo.
    ssh %conUsername%@%conIpAddress%

) ELSE (
    echo Wrong choice! Sorry!
)
```

Comment: you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @npocmaka,, thank you for the link! now I understood..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to set the variables.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set custom_choice=3
echo Which server do you want to connect?
echo 1. 232
echo 2. Kiwire Free Edition
echo 3. Custom
echo.
set /p choice="Enter your choice: "
echo.

IF %choice%==1 (
    ::this is comment
    ssh root@192.168.0.232
) ELSE IF %choice%==2 (
    ssh -i ./key/my-ssh-key-normal dev@123.123.123.123
) ELSE IF %choice%==%custom_choice% (
    set /p conIpAddress="Please insert IP Address: "
    set /p conUsername="Please insert Username: "
    echo.
    ssh !conUsername!@!conIpAddress!

) ELSE (
    echo Wrong choice! Sorry!
)
```

Comment: Because the user input expects known values, I would also recommend using the `Choice` command, _(if your OS is compatible)_. Enter `Choice /?` in your Command prompt for more information.